# Display Serial number using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My input XML consists of the following,

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <type>U</type>
        <value>111</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>X</type>
        <value>222</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>E</type>
        <value>333</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>Q</type>
        <value>444</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <value>555</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <value>666</value>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Output i required,

```
<ROOT>
    <ENTRY>
        <SLNO>1</SLNO>
        <VALUE>111</VALUE>
    </ENTRY>
    <ENTRY>
        <SLNO>1</SLNO>
        <VALUE>222</VALUE>
    </ENTRY>
    <ENTRY>
         <SLNO>1</SLNO>
         <VALUE>333</VALUE>
    </ENTRY>
    <ENTRY>
        <SLNO>2</SLNO>
        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
    </ENTRY>
    <ENTRY>
        <SLNO>3</SLNO>
        <VALUE>555<VALUE>
    </ENTRY>
    <ENTRY>
        <SLNO>4</SLNO>
        <VALUE>666</VALUE>
    </ENTRY>
</ROOT>
```

The requirement is to generate new SLNO for types other than X, E, Y and K and also if type tag itself is missing. For all other types we need to display new serial number.

I have written a for-each to for the same since i have to do some more processing with another values, so for-each is a must.

How can I achieve this?

My sample XSL code is asl follows,

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/ENTRY">
    <xsl:if test="(TYPE != 'X') and (TYPE != 'E')">             
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[<SLNO>]]></xsl:text>


        <xsl:if test="((type != 'X') and (type != 'E') and (type != 'Y') and (type != 'K'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::type[((. != 'X' and . != 'E' and . != 'Y' and . !='K') or . ='')]) + 1" /> 
        </xsl:if>                                                               

        <xsl:if test="(type = 'X') or (type = 'E') or (type = 'Y') or (type = 'K')">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::type[(. != 'X' and . != 'E' and . != 'Y' and . !='K')])" />                                                        
        </xsl:if>



        <xsl:text><![CDATA[</SLNO>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- Printing remaining values -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Problem with this code is, i'm not getting SLNO for entries that does not have type tag.

Please help.

Comment: Is your question fully correct. You mention "X, Y, K and L" in the question, but it there is a reference to "E" in the XSLT, but not "L"

Comment: @Tim, you are correct , i have updated it. sorry.

Comment: @Wilz: In your code you are generating *text* that looks like markup -- this doesn't produce at all the XML document you want as result. Learn *never* to produce markup-look-alike text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning**:

The code provided in this question isn't syntactically legal XSLT -- there is no XSLT instruction `<xsl:type-of>` in the language.

Also, this code generates *text* that looks like opening and closing element tags.

Never do such thing, when you want to generate an element -- test is not markup -- it is just ... text.; and the generated output is not what you wanted it to be.

---

**Solution**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry">
  <entry>
   <slno>
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "count((.
            |
              preceding-sibling::entry)
               [not(type)
               or
                not(contains('+X+E+Y+K+', concat('+', type, '+')))
                ]
            )"/>
    </slno>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::type)]"/>
  </entry>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <type>U</type>
        <value>111</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>X</type>
        <value>222</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>E</type>
        <value>333</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>Q</type>
        <value>444</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <value>555</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <value>666</value>
    </entry>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <entry>
      <slno>1</slno>
      <value>111</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <slno>1</slno>
      <value>222</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <slno>1</slno>
      <value>333</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <slno>2</slno>
      <value>444</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <slno>3</slno>
      <value>555</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <slno>4</slno>
      <value>666</value>
   </entry>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution Dimitre, and its working great. Can you plz provide me some reference to learn XSL, since i'm new to XSLT.

Comment: @Wilz: You are welcome. This answer contains pointers to good XSLT resources: http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305

Answer (score 1):

- Don't **EVER** use `<xsl:text><![CDATA[<SLNO>]]></xsl:text>` to output XML elements. Ever. This is just bad and wrong (and ugly at that, but ugly isn't even an argument here).
- Do not use `<xsl:for-each>`. Use `<xsl:template>`/`<xsl:apply-templates>`
- You can use `translate()` to your advantage, see below. **WARNING** This shortcut will only work if you have single letter types.
- Think if you *really* need to upper-case those element names. This does not look like a necessary change to me. Keeping the original case is much easier because you can use the [identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). Also see [Dimitre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293961/18771).

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <ROOT>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="entry" />
    </ROOT>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <ENTRY>
      <SLNO>
        <xsl:value-of select="
          count(
            (. | preceding-sibling::entry)[not(type and translate(type, 'EKXY', '') = '')]
          )
        " />
      </SLNO>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="value" />
    </ENTRY>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <VALUE>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </VALUE>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
<ROOT>
  <ENTRY>
    <SLNO>1</SLNO>
    <VALUE>111</VALUE>
  </ENTRY>
  <ENTRY>
    <SLNO>1</SLNO>
    <VALUE>222</VALUE>
  </ENTRY>
  <ENTRY>
    <SLNO>1</SLNO>
    <VALUE>333</VALUE>
  </ENTRY>
  <ENTRY>
    <SLNO>2</SLNO>
    <VALUE>444</VALUE>
  </ENTRY>
  <ENTRY>
    <SLNO>3</SLNO>
    <VALUE>555</VALUE>
  </ENTRY>
  <ENTRY>
    <SLNO>4</SLNO>
    <VALUE>666</VALUE>
  </ENTRY>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Tomalak: Good answer, but it doesn't produce the required result. Also, using `translate()` in this way would count a `<type>XXXY</type>`, which isn't wanted.

Comment: @Dimitre The question indicates single-letter types, so I took that as a reference. The OP *did* leave room for guessing, so that's one possible solution. But you are right, multi-letter types *would* make my code fail. I've added a note with this warning. The counting error in my logic is fixed.

Comment: Tomalak: Now that you have corrected the initial solution and included a warning +1 from me. It is still true that the more generic solution is applicable not only to XML document types with which the limited solution is working.

Comment: @Dimitre Absolutely. I wanted to show the possible shortcut, though, because it's not obvious that `translate()` can be used like this.

Comment: Tomalak: I was also thinking that to many people `translate()` seems more efficient than `contains()`. In fact the opposite maybe true if a good string-serching algorithm is used -- such as suffix trees.

Comment: @Dimitre It's primarily shorter (than the OP's approach at least). I can't make any statements towards performance, I suppose that's too variable between processors and needs to be measured individually.

Answer (score 0):

in your check

```
(TYPE != 'X') and (TYPE != 'E')
```

you need to include an 'OR' statement for ENTRY nodes that do not have the TYPE node'

something like

```
((TYPE != 'X') and (TYPE != 'E')) or count(TYPE) = 0
```

Comment: Tried the following, but not working, <xsl:type-of select="count(preceding::type[((. != 'X' and . != 'E' and . != 'Y' and . !='K') or count(.) =0)]) + 1" />